# load page with curl(windows) bat

Tags: windows, curl, batch-file

I downloaded curl for windows and i need a bat file which will load an url every 2 minutes. Any help?­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­
My solution:

```
@echo off
:again
    C:/curl.exe -I http://site.ru/cron.php
    timeout /T 60
goto again
```

Comment: What did you try already? Did do a Google search?

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna guess the problem is that `timeout` does not exist.

A common technique is to ping localhost for timeouts in batch scripts:

```
ping localhost -n 120
```